# How AWS DynamoDB query result is a list of items while partition key is a unique value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm new to AWS DynamoDB and wanted to clarify something.
As I learned when we use query we should use the partition key which is unique among the list of items, then how the result from a query is a list!!! it should be one row!! and why do we even need adding more condition?
I think I am missing something here, can someone please help me to understand?
I need this because I want to query on list of applications with specific status value or for specific range of time but if I am supposed to provide the appId what is the point of the condition?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Often your table will have [sort key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/), which together with your partition key will create [composite primary key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey). In this scenario a `query` can return multiple items. To return only one value, not a list, you can use [get_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.get_item) instead if you know unique value of the composite primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I don't need a unique item, actually I need a list of items in specific date and a list of items with specific status value. I thought of using query but then I learned that partition key is required, which doesn't make sense it is again like get item! How can I get a list of items?

Comment: also to your point even if I had a sort key, still my appId was unique and providing it in the query will result in just one item not a list!

Comment: @Roya No. With sort key, your appId maybe same. The composite key must be unique.

Comment: Thanks. Then, do you think in my case should I use scan?

Comment: @Roya Scan can be expensive. Check also local and global secondary indexes. Maybe having them will help you.